# Tagline AFTER Sign In

Tags: navigation

After the user signs in to your website, should we include taglines? If not, we can have a nice file menu style effect with the navigation bar. Examples: twitter and facebook.

The question is whether we should add one or two more lines to the navigation bar for the 'title' and 'tagline.' An good example of this is nngroup.com

Learn more about [taglines](http://www.nngroup.com/search/?q=tagline).

## **Menu-style Navigation Bars (1 line)**

[image]
[image]

## **Descriptive headers with navigation, tagline, and title**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of taglines usually is to provide a quick one-line description about your site/app etc. For a logged in user, it would be redundant to show them the tagline since they are familiar enough with your site/app to create an account/use it regularly.

You can probably take back the screen space at the top for other purpose once user has logged in as twitter and facebook has done.

A logged in user also usually have very different tasks as compared to a visitor browsing your site. It makes sense to modify the header to better suit their needs.